# P4V insists on submitting files that are not in my workspace

Tags: perforce

Say I have the following depot on my Perforce server:

```
//depot/source/...
//depot/unwanted/...
//depot/unrelated/...
```

Initially, I set up my workspace as follows:

```
Workspace name: my_workspace
Workspace root: D:\project\
//depot/source/...   //my_workspace/source/...
//depot/unwanted/... //my_workspace/unwanted/...
```

Then I realized I didn't need to sync the `unwanted` folder, so I removed the last line from the mappings, yielding the following:

```
Workspace name: my_workspace
Workspace root: D:\project\
//depot/source/... //my_workspace/source/...
```

From what I understand, P4V should now not care about tracking the files in `unwanted`. However, every time I make changes to files in the `source` folder and want to submit them, the submit list includes files in `//depot/unwanted`, as if the changes in the mappings were not applied. I also tried to delete my workspace and make a new one, but P4V refuses because the files in `unwanted` are opened, but I just want them to be ignored by P4V.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are open (it sounds like they are if they're being included in submit), you need to `revert` them to explicitly discard the pending changes and unmap them from the workspace. If they're open for add, revert will by default "abandon" the files and leave them as local-only (and writable).

For previously-submitted depot files (*note: this is not relevant if the files in "unwanted" are simply open for add but were never submitted*), you need to `sync` your workspace ("get latest") after changing the mappings in order to update the local tree to match the new view (i.e. remove the depot files that are no longer mapped to your workspace).  I think P4V will automatically prompt you to do this if you change your client mappings.

Comment: That is such an odd design choice! I need to sync files in order to remove them from my workspace, but I removed them from my workspace explicitly to not have to sync them!

Comment: Is there a way to see the actual workspace mappings then, instead of only the ones we wish for?

Comment: I tried your suggestion to revert the files, with the option to remove the files from the workspace, but it deleted the files from the computer... So if I understand correctly, does this really mean there is no way to ask Perforce to ignore files that are different from the depot?

Comment: I *believe* all you had to do was do the revert without checking that "remove files" option.  Files that are opened for add are abandoned (not deleted) by default.  Files that are open for edit are reverted to the depot version by default; you can override that with the `-k` flag at the command line.

Comment: To see the "actual" (synced) content of your workspace independent of the mappings, use `p4 have` -- or look at the file tree in P4V.  Sync to bring the local tree in line with the view.  Note that open files (i.e. files in a pending changelist) will not be updated by a sync operation.

Comment: Worth noting that files you haven't added to the depot yet are a somewhat different ball of wax from files you *have* added to the depot that you now want to have untracked local copies of (while preserving the existing depot files).  Both scenarios are easy to accomplish but the steps are going to be a little different for each -- for the former case a simple `revert` does the trick, in the latter case you'll want to use `revert -k` and `sync -k`.  If your `unwanted` folder is truly unwanted and you don't even want your local copy, vanilla `revert`/`sync` is all you need.

Comment: In my case, `unwanted` is wanted locally (maybe I chose a bad name for my example), but I don't want it to be synced (it contains intermediate builds, logs, and so on). Now that its content was made writable by the compile process, I'm trying to revert the files without checking the remove option to finally untrack them, but P4V does nothing and says "no files reverted (all files were either changed or opened for add, delete or branch)". They don't seem to be abandoned.

Comment: Sounds like the files are indeed open for add and you did something like "Revert Unchanged" (`revert -a`).  There should be a regular old "Revert".  Do that.